# How to find Log10(x) without Math library

Tags: python

I have the following code. I need to calculate log10(x) without math function. How can i do this?

```
class Solution(object):
    def findPower(self, number, exponent):
        resultPower = 1
        for i in range(1, int(exponent) + 1):
            resultPower = resultPower * number
        return resultPower

    def log10(self,x):
       ...

    def mySqrt(self, x):
        return self.findPower(10, (self.log10(x)) / 2)
```

I've found the formulas.

[image: formula]
[image: formula]

But how i should use it ?

Comment: idk for the log but the sqrt can be `x**(1/2)` for squareroot or `x**(1/3)` for cubicroot

Comment: ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...  You can use that plus the base change formula.